# How to close the window by clicking on a specific range through javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to ask that I made a pop-up window. I want to click the gray part after the pop-up window to close the entire popup, but click the yellow block to close the popup. But I am a novice in programming and don’t know how to write this to achieve it. I hope it can be done. Get everyone's help, thank you!

```js
$('.js-btn').on('click',function(e){
  $('.popup').css('display','flex');
})
```

```css
.popup {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
}
.popup .wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="js-btn">click</button>

<div class="popup">
  <div class="wrap">content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, make a global variable named `isPopupOpen`. While opening the popup, you can set `isPopupOpen` to true.

Then you can try the bellow code:

```js
$("body").on("click", function(e) {
    if (isPopupOpen) {
        // your code
        isPopupOpen = false;
    }
});
```